# Algorithm to park cars with minimal moves (2nd version)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

I'm working on a car move problem. Suppose we have origin parking position for each car, `[-1,1,2,3,7,6,4,5]` (which means first position is empty, car with ID 1 parked at 2nd position, car with ID 2 parked at 3rd position), we want to find the minimal move to re-park car as specific desired positions. For example specific desired position `[4,6,5,1,7,3,2,-1]` means car with ID 4 parked at first position, car with ID 6 parked as 2nd position, etc. `-1` means empty parking lot to utilize.

My 2nd version of code is based on the great thought and implementation from Joe ([Algorithm to park cars with minimal moves](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145174/algorithm-to-park-cars-with-minimal-moves)), since it is new code, I make a new post other than changing the original post.

Here is my code, my major idea for what I think Joe's code needs some change,

1. Each time we move car `a` from position `x` to position `y`, we just make a **move**, we are not **swap**, which is first point I change Joe's code. I change (move) position of car `a` to position `y` and then update position `y` to empty;
2. Based on logic of 1st item, I think we should check for `output[index] != empty`, other than check for `output[index] != input[index]` to end of internal `while` loop.

**My code mainly based on Joe's code**,

```
def car_move_v2(input, output, empty=0):
    # print move from position a to positive b
    def print_move(a, b):
        input[b] = input[a]
        input[a] = empty
        position[input[a]] = a
        position[input[b]] = b
        print('{0}, {1} -> {2}'.format(input[b], a, b))
    position = {
        pos: index
        for index, pos in enumerate(input)
    }
    for start in range(len(input)):
        if input[start] == output[start]:
            continue
        if input[start] != empty:
            print_move(start, position[empty])
        index = start
        while output[index] != empty:
            prev_index = index
            index = position[output[prev_index]]
            print_move(index, prev_index)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    car_move_v2([-1,1,2,3,7,6,4,5], [4,6,5,1,7,3,2,-1],-1)
```

**Output**,

```
4, 6 -> 0
2, 2 -> 6
5, 7 -> 2
1, 1 -> 7
6, 5 -> 1
3, 3 -> 5
1, 7 -> 3
```

Comment: (_majorly_ is quite different from _mainly_ or _essentially_.)

Comment: @greybeard, you mean different? Confused.

Comment: I had to look up _majorly_: seems to see most use in informal American English, with an interpretation of _to a high degree_ (from [_very_ to _extremely_](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/majorly)). [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/majorly) was the one source I encountered listing first what I presume you intend: _primarily_ - to go on to join the pack in the `Defined for English Language Learners` section.

Comment: @greybeard, thanks, changed to mainly to reduce any confusions. If you have any thoughts on my original question, it will be great. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need a separate `position` dict, that you have to maintain whenever you move a car ? You can just use `input.index(car_id)` anytime you need to get a car position.
Also your `print_move()` function is almost useless, since it just swaps 2 positions, one of which is assumed to be empty. That could be written in a single line.

Here are my proposed improvements, with an modified `move()` that takes the car id to move and the target free slot, and returns the new freed slot:

```
def car_move_v2(initial_slots, target_slots, EMPTY=None):
    current_slots = initial_slots # will use as working slots
    def move(car, free_slot):
        "move car to free_slot, returns the newly freed slot"
        assert current_slots[free_slot] == EMPTY, "Slot {0} is not free".format(free_slot)
        car_slot = current_slots.index(car)
        current_slots[free_slot], current_slots[car_slot] = current_slots[car_slot], EMPTY
        print('car {0} moved from {1} to {2}, {3}'.format(car, car_slot, free_slot, current_slots))
        return car_slot

    for slot, (current_car, target_car) in enumerate(zip(current_slots, target_slots)):
        if current_car == target_car: # if car is already in target position, do not move
            continue
        elif current_car != EMPTY: # if there is an unwanted car in the slot, move it to the empty slot
            free_slot = move(current_car, current_slots.index(EMPTY))
        else:
            free_slot = slot
        # at this point we have a free slot to work with
        while target_slots[free_slot] != EMPTY:
            other_target_car = target_slots[free_slot]
            free_slot = move(other_target_car, free_slot) # move that car to the current free pos


if __name__ == "__main__":
    car_move_v2(initial_slots=[None,1,2,3,7,6,4,5], target_slots=[4,6,5,1,7,3,2,None], EMPTY=None)
```

Comment: Thanks Guillaume for the code and vote up. I think `input.index(car_id)` time complexity is `O(n)` for look-up index for a value, while a dictionary look-up is `O(1)`, so my method is more efficient?

Comment: BTW, your overall coding style is much better than mine, love it and learning. My only question for your code is above comment. :)

Comment: True about the dict lookup being faster (O(1)) , but for a 8 elements list that doesn't matter much.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Guillaume, mark your reply as answer and grant bounty points.